# How can I inject invalid XML chars in an Exchange appointment for testing?

Tags: xml, unicode, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm synchronizing with Exchange (either 2013 or 365) through EWS. My (Delphi) code process the SOAP XML requests and responses.

We have seen [invalid XML characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets) like `#xB` in the returned SOAP `<body>` elements with some of our clients (*Don't ask me how they got there - and I no longer have access to those 'corrupt' messages*) which our subsequent XML processing code can't handle.

I have now built a filter routine and need to test that, but I have failed to create an appointment with an invalid Unicode character either through Outlook or IE.

Does anyone know of a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Mapi (either via the OOM,Redemption or probably [MFCMapi](https://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/) is the easiest as it allows you to edit the property directly) you should be able to write to the MAPI property for the body directly (or get a MSG export of the Message from the problem environment and import that into a Mailbox via Outlook should bring the issue into your test environment).

Appointments should have RTF body so the corruption maybe happening because there is an editor that is writing to these props in the wrong format or there are issue in the conversion.

Mfcmapi will let you edit the body property directly just drop in the Hex value for what would be invalid data you don't need to write any code:

[image]